# split column containing list into dummies columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to split the column `Technologies` into dummies columns containing only one technology, in other words to get one column Matlab, another one Python etc..

I've started with `df['Technologies'].str.split("/").to_list()` but then I'm blocked.
Below the dataframe that I was given:

```
    Job                 Technologies                                       City
0   Data scientist      Matlab/Python/Pyspark/Scikit-learn/Tensorflow      Paris
1   Data architecte     Python/Java/Scala/MongoDB                          Marseille
2   Lead data scientist SPSS/SQL/Teradata/R/Python/Tensorflow/scikit-learn Nantes
3   Data scientist      C/C++/Java/Python                                  Marseille
4   Data scientist      Matlab/Python/C++/numpy/Tensorflow/scikit-learn    Bordeaux
```

The result I would like to expect :

```
    Job                 Matlab Python Pyspark Scikit-learn ... C++ Teradata City
0   Data scientist      0      1      1       1                0   0        Paris
1   Data architecte     0      0      0       0                0   1        Marseille
2   Lead data scientist 1      0      0       1                1   0        Nantes
3   Data scientist      1      0      1       0                0   1        Marseille
4   Data scientist      0      1      0       1                1   1        Bordeaux
```

Comment: why does the `City` `Nates` have 1 for `matlab`?

Comment: The result that I've written is just an example. The only thing I need to find out is how to split and get dummies of ```Technologies``` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach, although you will have to do some cleaning after

`df = pd.get_dummies(df['Technologies'].str.split('/', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower(), axis=1))`

Rename columns

`df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str.get(1)`

Sum duplicated columns

`df = df.groupby(lambda x: x, axis=1).sum()`

```
 c  c++  java  matlab  mongodb  numpy  pyspark  python  r  scala  scikit-learn  spss  sql  tensorflow  teradata
0  0    0     0       1        0      0        1       1  0      0             1     0    0           1         0
1  0    0     1       0        1      0        0       1  0      1             0     0    0           0         0
2  0    0     0       0        0      0        0       1  1      0             1     1    1           1         1
3  1    1     1       0        0      0        0       1  0      0             0     0    0           0         0
4  0    1     0       1        0      1        0       1  0      0             1     0    0           1         0
```